# Static object thread safety

Tags: c#, multithreading, static, thread-safety, static-members

I have a pre-loaded static xmldocument object which has errorcode and it descriptions,
If i am using multi threaded application and trying to get a error code description for particular  error code, Do i need to put a lock on that method or not.

Here is my code in brief (Pls. ignore the implementation of GetErrorCodeDescription method, Only consider that _oXmlDoc has been used ),

Pre-loaded static xmldocument
**_oXmlDoc**

later i am calling GetErrorCodeDescription method to get an error code description like this ,

```
Public string GetErrorCodeDescription(string errorCode)
{
string errorDEscption="";

    XmlNodeList elemList = **_oXmlDoc**.GetElementsByTagName(errorCode);

    for (int i=0; i < elemList.Count; i++)
    {   
      errorDEscption=elemList[i].InnerXml);
    }  

return errorDEscption;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would be better off doing this parsing of XML just once and putting all error codes and corresponding descriptions into a dictionary. If you use [ConcurrentDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191%28VS.100%29.aspx) for this, you should be safe.

Comment: ConcurrentDictionary is unnecessarily slow. The normal Dictionary _is_ thread-safe for just reaing.

Answer (score 0):

From [the XmlDocument docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx);

> Thread Safety
>
> Any public static (Shared in Visual Basic) members of this type are thread safe. **Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe.**

So, no, use of your static instance is not guaranteed to be thread safe without locking.

Comment: @user3597242 There's no provision in the docs for thread safety for read operations. Querying the object may - for example - build caches using non thread safe collections.

Comment: Formally correct but this is template-text on MSDN. I would be surprised if read-only wasn't safe, but the only way to be sure is to check the source or find a more authorative statement.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I think you'd be hard pressed to find anyone giving more guarantees on thread safety than the docs do. As far as I understand the .NET memory model, if there is no [fence](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part4.aspx) between constructing the object and reading it, it may be incompletely written to memory when the first read on another CPU occurs. Not necessarily a problem here, but hard to rule out and a very nasty problem to find when it occurs.

Comment: Please note, i am constructing/loading xmldocument at windows service Start event , after that the loaded static instance will be used as mentioned in above code in timer_tick threads.Since it has been created single thread environment and being reading in multi threaded environment , i feel it is thread safe. pls .correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: @user3597242 It _may_ be, but it's not _guaranteed_ to be thread safe. Even if it is now, it may change in a future .NET version. The docs don't say either way, they're just saying "don't assume it is".

Comment: If it is reading only, that means no data will be changed on xmldocument object . So what will be the impact if it is  being read by different threads. Is there can be a collision of threads or something like that because of it is a single object

Comment: @user3597242 There's as far as I can see no guarantee on the object not being updated on a read operation. It may for example employ caching in a non thread safe manner, building a hash table with the contents, so that the next operation gets faster. The text in the manual is Microsoft's way of saying "We didn't build this to be thread safe, we didn't test it to be thread safe and we don't guarantee anything if you use if with multiple threads. It may work and if you use it as if it were thread safe, good luck, but don't call us about it when it fails".

Comment: @user3597242 Sorry if I sound harsh, it's not my intent. I'm not defending that it's not thread safe or shouldn't be, I'm just saying if you're looking for some kind of guarantee that it'll work, it's just not available.